# CTRL + SHIFT + key when using CTRL+SHIFT to switch keyboard layout

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

OS - El Loki stable.

Hello! I have a problem when i use PHPStorm or something.
For example i need to Push my commits to git. I press ctrl+shift+k and keyboard layout switch first, and CTRL+SHIFT+K not works.

Is there any fix of this?

This also happens with other keyboard shortcut's (CTRL+SHIFT+C, CTRL+SHIF+F etc)

Comment: check if that keyboard shortcuts are not associated with other commands in the config > keyboard. Are these shortcuts (CTRL+SHIFT+K) working within oher programs?

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and I decided to change the keyboard shortcut to change language on Alt + Space yet.

Comment: No, all shortcut's with CTRL + SHIFT + key - just switch layout

Comment: @Rho In Terminal when i press CTRL+SHIFT + A _Loki_ select all TEXT, but layout switched to next language

Comment: what shortcut are you using to change layout on Settings>Keyboard>Layout?

Comment: @santileortiz " I press ctrl+shift+k and keyboard layout switch first, " => i use CTRL + SHIFT

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is the default shortcut for changing keyboard layouts in Loki, so you'll need to change that if you want to use the same modifier keys for other shortcuts.

You can do this at `Settings > Keyboard pane > Layout subtab > "Switch layout"`

[image: Keyboard Layout]

Comment: No. Because ALT + SHIFT + key will do smth. Just switch layout no more.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by no—we would need to know more about what exactly is conflicting

Comment: i want to use CTRL + SHIFT to switch layout. i have been using CTRL+SHIFT more than ten years. It's force of habit. Now i'm using UBUNTU 16.04 where those hotkeys are working.

Comment: In my screenshot above, you can use Ctrl+Shift to switch keyboard layouts... The only issue would be conflicts with other Ctrl+Shift+K-style shortcuts. You're saying you can use Ctrl+Shift+K in Ubuntu without it also changing your keyboard layout?

Comment: I do not understand you.

I use ubuntu with CTRL+SHIFT layout switch. In PHPStorm all shortcuts  are working perfectly.

I want to use Loki but in Loki I can't use those hotkeys.
At all i use hotkeys with CTRL + SHIFT + key, CTRL + ALT + key; ALT + SHIFT + key and others

Comment: I'm not sure how Ubuntu does it, my guess is Ctrl+Shift only works after you release some of the keys, maybe all layout switching shortcuts should be triggered on release and not on press, but I'm not completely sure about this. Can you test if all layout switching keybindings are release based on Ubuntu? I've reported the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1629505, your feedback over there is always appreciated.

Comment: @santileortiz i have already report this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1627544
In ubuntu wheni hold CTRL+SHIFT  NOTHING happens, when i unhold CTRL + SHIFT - keyboard layout changes. In Elementary OS - when i hold CTRL + SHIFT - LAYOUT changes. There is no chance to use CTRL + SHIFT + key in Elementary OS.

In ubuntu every shortcut with CTRL+SHIFT+key are works perfectly.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I my self switched from ubuntu and didn't know that this bug exists. but I have found that this bug is actually really old, you can spend some time to read it but in short, there are several patches proposed over the past years, and they are against the specification?

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865

So, I have no knowledge of Xorg patching, but I guess the patches that are proposed over there can solve it.

`[Didn't want to post this as an answer, but I couldn't comment because of my rep]`