# Can't use Alt+Shift anymore if it set to switch keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I was set Alt + Shift to switch between Thai and US and works fine

But I need to use Alt + Shift + (other) key for VSCode but didn't work any help?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this

[CTRL + SHIFT + key when using CTRL+SHIFT to switch keyboard layout](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/ctrl-shift-key-when-using-ctrlshift-to-switch-keyboard-layout)

, and at this

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1245473

---

Workaround is to change Layout switch to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or something...

Also there is another workaround for Ubuntu on the bottom of the page

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1683383

, but it doesn't works with eOS Juno beta 2.